# VBA borderless print

Tags: vba

I have to set up a page in Excel VBA ... the problem is that the page must be borderless. So not just the usual way of the option left,right, top etc. , I also have to manipulate the printer to ensure that no border will be seen... well, I can do that manually, but even if I record the macro... after I finsihed I found out that nothing had been recorded at all for this issue .... don't need help with any macro recording I did it wright... the macro is there... with sub ..... but no VB Code at all... I also could code it manualy.. but how... there isn't any printer object.... any solution ?

Comment: The printer configuration is handled by the printer driver. Excel is bypassed.

Comment: thanks , but how can I retrieve the printer driver ?

Comment: If I knew that I would have left an answer.

Comment: You've probably figured this out by now, but creating a printout with no margin is called "full bleed" and is something that your average desktop printer cannot do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following  code should help you.

```
    Public Sub PrintButton1_Click()
    Dim CurrRange As Range, CurrRange2 As Range

    Set CurrRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:--")
    Set CurrRange2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rough").Range("A1:--")
    CurrRange2.ClearContents
    CurrRange.Copy
    CurrRange2.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders
```

above statement should paste the content in the format you want to take printout.

Then setup the page using the following code and print

```
    With PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    CurrRange2.PrintOut 1, 1, 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the border is still there... I guess I have to do with PostScript... as I need sth to retrieve the printer driver... I have a Canon MP490... if there is a easy way to code it .....